# How to prevent converting parameter character when reloading the current page in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I use (~) character for my url parameter on my page

`http://localhost:8000/clients?page=2&filter=type~active`

And if I'm force to reload the page, the (~) character turn into (%) so this is my url after reloading the page

`http://localhost:8000/clients?page=2&filter=type%active`

I tried search this problem using the title of this question as my keyword, but the result are far from the problem.

Comment: The [example code in the spec](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#example-constructing-urlsearchparams) covers this exact case.

Comment: Short answer: Don't use characters that might have a special meaning in a URL